# Array Not Being Recognized Inside Plist - iOS

Tags: ios, plist

I am having trouble accessing an array placed in this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PageTitle</key>
        <string>Title</string>
        <key>Filters</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Filter</key>
                <string>SomeFilter</string>
                <key>Param</key>
                <string>SomeParam</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Filter</key>
                <string>SomeFilter2</string>
                <key>Param</key>
                <string>SomeParam2</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
   </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

My code is as follows (path has been set correctly):

```
NSMutableArray* propertyFile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [propertyFile objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray* filters = [dict[@"Filters"] mutableCopy];
```

The 'dict' variable returns with only one key/value pair, which is the 'PageTitle' key.  The 'Filters' key is not being recognized.  Very new to iOS and seem to be spinning my tires trying to fix this.

Comment: You are loading the plist into `propertyList`, but getting the dict from `propertyFile`. Can you post missing code if any? Otherwise that could be the problem

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my case.  The only other code I have is currently to get the path, which it does correctly.  The **dict** variable does get set, but only with that single key/value pair as stated.  I havent added any more code after since my **filters** variable doesn't have any members.

Comment: As a side note: Don't set to mutable types from the plist because  unless you do a `mutableCopy` they will be immutable.

Comment: You are probably loading an old version of the file. Try cleaning and building if you haven't done yet.

Comment: @Peter Have you verified that the actual plist referenced by `path` truly has the data you think it does? Perhaps through a build quirk, the plist in the built app's bundle isn't what you think it is.

Comment: It would seem that was the case.  I cleaned, and changed the file name.  This time it loaded the edited version and worked exactly as expected.  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code and I get your filters as expected. Have you tried printing out your filters in NSLog?

```
2013-02-26 08:01:38.162 test[24849:c07] filters = (
        {
        Filter = SomeFilter;
        Param = SomeParam;
    },
        {
        Filter = SomeFilter2;
        Param = SomeParam2;
    }
)
```

Comment: hmmmm.  well thats sure odd. i will try that out.

Comment: well i changed the file name of my plist and reran everything.  This time the filters showed up.  Makes me think that the simulator was caching the plist file? Either way thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Peter I think you are spot on the plist will not normally be recopied when you go build and play.  Next time try doing a clean before you build and that should solve your issue :)

Comment: Please report that as a bug to Apple. It's very annoying behavior and the more people that report it the better the chance of it getting fixed. (We have the same problem with image files all of the time)